# Printing out an Array that was passed by Referenced that was in a Class

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pass-by-reference

I am confused on how would i Print out all the elements in aVect and bVect. From my understanding, inside of the int main the float FloatArray1 holds 10 spots, which are all filled up with the numbers inside of the {} next to it. Afterwards, that Array and the array size, which is 10, is being passed into a class object named aVect. 
What I am confused is, how would I print the elements in aVect when nothing is being passed to the void printElement function? From what I was taught about arrays, if it was something like

```
int array[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}
for (int i =0; i < 5; i++)
{cout << array[i] << endl;}
```

But then that only works because is it directly in the same scope of code. In the code below, the printElements function will be used for both aVect and bVect so it can't be passed specifically by reference and can't be done like the way above. Could anyone help me try to figure this? Barely learning the basics of classes and functions.

```
 class FloatVectArray {
 public:
void printElements();  // prints all elements in the vector
private:
float *vector;      // the vector
int vectorsize; // size of the vector 

void FloatVectArray::printElements() 
{
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    cout <<  << endl;
}
}

int main() {
// testing the implementation of a float vector using array
// declare & initialize an array of floats and create a float vector aVect 
float FloatArray1[10] = { 2.1, 7.2, 3.3, 6.4, 1.5, 43.6,72.7,19.8,39.9, 71.1 };
FloatVectArray aVect(FloatArray1, 10);
cout << "Printing all elements in aVect:" << endl;
aVect.printElements();

// declare & initialize another array of floats and create float vector bVect
float FloatArray2[10] = { 1.1, 2.2, 5.3, 6.4, 1.5, 7.6, 9.7,17.8, 92.9, 42.1 };
FloatVectArray bVect(FloatArray2, 10);
cout << "Printing all elements in bVect:" << endl;
bVect.printElements();
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using a pointer to `std::vector`?

Comment: This is the skeleton code my professor gave us, I only wrote the for loop inside of the void printElement function. Left the inside blank since i know we're going to have to display something, just don't know what.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i > 10; i++)` - Will this ever loop?

Comment: Your original code will work, if you just use `vector` and `vectorsize` instead of `array` and `5`.

Comment: No, sorry I did not notice the error in signs. Just fixed*

Comment: @BoPersson I used the array and 5 as an example of what I was taught about how to display the elements inside of an array. The actual issue is in the bigger block of code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, the thing you are missing is that because its

```
void FloatVectArray::printElements()
```

and not

```
void printElements()
```

the members of the `class FloatVectArray` are in scope for body of the function. You can simply access them by their name:

```
cout << vector[i] << endl;
```

if you really wanted you could explicitly scope the member variable:

```
cout << FloatVectArray::vector[i] << endl;
```

but that is not necessary in this case.

Better to adjust the for-loop accordingly of course

```
for (int i = 0; i < vectorsize; i++)
```

If I understand you right, your aim is this understanding classes thing but anyway two more hints:

- If you simply copy the pointer to the array, like I did in the completed code below, your FloatVectArray will have a dangling pointer if the passed-in array expires, thats bad
- start working with well-thougt whitespace from the beginning. It makes your code easier to read and frees brain capacity for more important thing.

completed code for your reference:

```
#include <iostream>

class FloatVectArray {
public:
    FloatVectArray(float* v, int size) :vector(v), vectorsize(size) {};
    void printElements();  // prints all elements in the vector
private:
    float *vector;      // the vector
    int vectorsize; // size of the vector
};

void FloatVectArray::printElements()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorsize; i++)
    {
        std::cout << vector[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // testing the implementation of a float vector using array
    // declare & initialize an array of floats and create a float vector aVect
    float FloatArray1[10] = { 2.1, 7.2, 3.3, 6.4, 1.5, 43.6,72.7,19.8,39.9, 71.1 };
    FloatVectArray aVect(FloatArray1, 10);
    std::cout << "Printing all elements in aVect:" << std::endl;
    aVect.printElements();

    // declare & initialize another array of floats and create float vector bVect
    float FloatArray2[10] = { 1.1, 2.2, 5.3, 6.4, 1.5, 7.6, 9.7,17.8, 92.9, 42.1 };
    FloatVectArray bVect(FloatArray2, 10);
    std::cout << "Printing all elements in bVect:" << std::endl;
    bVect.printElements();
    return 0;
}
```